# How do I take a screenshot with PHP Selenium WebDriver HTMLUnitWithJS?

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, remotewebdriver

I tried

```
$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::htmlUnitWithJS();
$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities, 5000);
...
$driver->takeScreenshot('tmp.png');
```

But it fails with this error

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnknownServerException' with message 'org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot' in /cygdrive/c/Users/Chloe/workspace/Teads/php-webdriver/lib/WebDriverExceptions.php:79

(No results in Google http://goo.gl/9SyjvO.) This is how the documentation says to use it.

https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/wiki/Taking-Full-Screenshot-and-of-an-Element

The version of Selenium is selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar

Comment: Have you tried this one (HtmlUnit driver with screenshot support)? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-developers/PTR_j4xLVRM

Comment: @StasS No. That's for Java, and written in 2011. The Facebook PHP library is newer (and in PHP).